# Linker Error causing problems

Tags: c

```
/home/crbt/AUT/SVN/version1.1/Code/poly6.3/linux/i386/gcc/lib/libpat.a(polymem.o): In function `poly_memory_init':
    polymem.cxx:(.text+0x71): undefined reference to `FastNew(unsigned int)'
    polymem.cxx:(.text+0x76): undefined reference to `FastDelete(void*)'
    polymem.cxx:(.text+0x81): undefined reference to `init_new_and_delete(void* (*)(unsigned int), void (*)(void*))'
    polymem.cxx:(.text+0xab): undefined reference to `MemoryHandler::Create(MemoryHandlerInitStruct*)'
    polymem.cxx:(.text+0xbe): undefined reference to `WarmNew(unsigned int)'
    polymem.cxx:(.text+0xc3): undefined reference to `WarmDelete(void*)'
    polymem.cxx:(.text+0xcc): undefined reference to `init_new_and_delete(void* (*)(unsigned int), void (*)(void*))'
```

I fail to understand the reason behind the linker errors. I navigated to the path mentioned above and found the `libpat.a` file to be intact.

Answer (score 0):

The error means that the linked modules are missing a definition of the named items `FastNew(unsigned int)`, etc.  That is, some code references the item, but there is no implementation of it.

This could have several classes of cause:

- a library is missing from the link
- a module is compiled incorrectly:  mismatched options, #defines, or `C` vs. `C++`
- a module is mistakenly linked which should not have been

From the types of modules referenced, I think the cause is likely the first one.  Look for a memory management library which should be included.